# Accessing selected values like an Array in JavaScript

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I know you can access the first element like this
`$(".myClass:first")`

But is there a way to do it with an index like in JavaScript `.getElementsbyClassname("MyClass").[0]`?

Something like:
`$(".MyClass:[5]")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I personally use this.

```
$(".myClass").eq(index);
```

Also you can get the element index among the matched elements [here](http://api.jquery.com/index/). For example:

```
$(".myClass").click(function(){
    $(this).index();
});
```

Comment: _"get the element index among the matched elements"_? `$(".myClass").index(this)`.

Answer (score 3):

yes there just use the selector "eq"

```
$(".MyClass:eq(5)")
```

http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

Comment: I always like to point out this note from the documentation when mentioning `:eq`:  "Because :eq() is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :eq() cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. For better performance in modern browsers, use $("your-pure-css-selector").eq(index) instead."

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".MyClass:nth-child(5)")
```

[:nth-child()](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

Comment: One important difference between `nth-child` and the `eq` selector is the `nth-child` is 1-based whereas `eq` is 0-based.

Comment: nth-child also does not work with all browsers that a company may be trying to support, e.g., corporate customers who don't upgrade IE versions quickly.

Answer (score 1):

These will give you a jQuery object containing the element at that index:

```
$(".MyClass:eq(5)")
$(".MyClass:eq(" + idx + ")")
$(".MyClass").eq(idx);
```

This will give you the element at the index:

```
$(".MyClass")[idx]
$(".MyClass").get(idx)
```